# compare timestamp between two tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a table "Summary" contains "ID", "NAME" and "Timestamp", I want to insert into this table all the rows from my DB table when the timestamp of the DB row is greater than MAX(TIMESTAMP) of the "Summary" table.

For example,

Summary table

| ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2018-06-28 15:12:46 |
| 2 | B | 2018-06-28 16:12:46 |
| 3 | C | 2018-06-28 18:12:46 |

DB table

| ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | 2018-06-28 15:12:46 |
| 2 | E | 2018-06-28 19:12:46 |
| 3 | F | 2018-06-28 22:12:46 |

SO, the MAX(timestamp) of "Summary" table is "2018-06-28 18:12:46", I need to check if there's any row in DB has a timestamp greater than that, if so, select the row from the DB and insert it into "Summary" table

desired table

| ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2018-06-28 15:12:46 |
| 2 | B | 2018-06-28 16:12:46 |
| 3 | C | 2018-06-28 18:12:46 |
| 2 | E | 2018-06-28 19:12:46 |
| 3 | F | 2018-06-28 22:12:46 |

I have tried this by comparing the two tables but it doesn't work:

SELECT
*

FROM DB , SUMMARY
WHERE DB.timestamp >= MAX(SUMMARY.timestamp );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your SQL:

```
SELECT *

FROM DB , SUMMARY WHERE DB.timestamp >= MAX(SUMMARY.timestamp );
```

Turn the attempt to get a max into a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB WHERE DB.timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) from SUMMARY );
```

The query you're showing is attempting a lateral join, BTW. The optimizer will resolve the max(timestamp) in a separate step to a scalar value, and then run the main query using it for the >= comparison.